# Calculating stability and order of implicit midpoint scheme

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Consider solving $y'(t) = f(t,y(t))$ by the implicit midpoint method:
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h \cdot f \left(t_n + \frac{h}{2},\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1})}{2} \right).
$$
I want to determine the order and regions of stability for this method.

1. Order. My first idea was to do the following: Substitute the exact solution.
   \begin{align*}
   &y(t_{n+1}) - \left[ y(t_n) + h \cdot f \left(t_n + \frac{h}{2},\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1})}{2} \right) \right] \\
   =& [ y(t_n) + hy '(t_n) + \frac{1}{2} h^2 y''(t_n) + O(h^3) ] \\
   - & [ y(t_n) + h \left[ y'(t_n) + \frac{1}{2} h y''(t_n) + O(h^2) \right]
   \end{align*}
   which is $O(h^3)$. But I don't think I can substitute in for the last part $f(t,y(t)) = y'(t)$ since $\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1})}{2} \neq y \left( t_n +  \frac{h}{2} \right)$ . . . It's only an approximation.
2. Stability. Apply to the test problem $y'(t) = f(t,y(t)) = \lambda y(t)$. This is done here ([Determine a stability region?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1975043/determine-a-stability-region?rq=1)), but again $f(\cdot, y(\cdot))$ is not of the form $f(t, y(t))$, so I don't know why the solution is valid. In particular, why is the test problem $y' =f(t,y(t)) =  \lambda y(t)$ applied to $f(t_{n+1/2} , (y_n + y_{n+1})/2)$ equal to $\lambda (y_n + y_{n+1})/2$?

The questions are similar and I probably have some misconception on numerics that is (hopefully) easy to clarify.

EDIT: Should I just think about $f \left(t_n + \frac{h}{2},\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1})}{2} \right)$ as $f(t_{n+1/2} , y_{n+1/2})$? If so I think my question is answered, but I would appreciate someone wiser in the field taking a look.

Comment: In answer to two, your ODE has no explicit $t$ dependence, so $f(t, y) = f(y) = \lambda y$. Hence $$f(t_{n+1/2}, (y_{n} + y_{n+1})/2) = f((y_{n} + y_{n+1})/2) = \lambda (y_{n} + y_{n+1})/2$$ Also, see [this](http://people.clarkson.edu/~gyao/ma571/hw1s.pdf) for an answer to your first question.

Comment: @Mattos Thanks for the quick reply. For the link you gave, it seems they show that the difference between $\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1}) }{2}$ and $y( t_n + \frac{h}{2})$ is $- \frac{h^2}{8} y'' \left(  t_n + \frac{h}{2} \right) + O(h^3)$. But how do they get the order of the overall scheme -- the last line doesn't make sense to me. And they don't seem to use $f$ at all.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1248062/115115, or use directly the well-known second order difference quotient $$\frac{y(t_{n+1})-2y(t_{n+\frac12})+y(t_n)}{h^2/4}=y''(t_{n+\frac12})+O(h^2)$$ to connect $\frac{y(t_{n+1})+y(t_n)}2$ and $y(t_{n+\frac12})$.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1:

$y_{n+1} = y_n + h \;\; f\left(t_n + \frac{h}{2}, \frac{y_n + y_{n+1}}{2} \right)$

$ = y_n + h \;\; f\left(t_{n+{\frac{1}{2}}}, y_{n+{\frac{1}{2}}} \right)$

$ = y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left(\; f(t_n,y_n) + f(t_{n+1},y_{n+1}) \; \right)$

$ = y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left(\; y'_{n} + y'_{n+1} \; \right)$

Now, replacing the approximate solution by the exact Taylor expanded counterparts:

$y_{n+1} - \left[ y_n + \frac{h}{2} \left(\; y'_{n} + y'_{n+1} \; \right) \right] = $

$y(t_{n+1}) - \left[ y(t_n) + \frac{h}{2} \left(\; y'(t_n) + y'(t_{n+1}) \; \right) \right] = $

$\left[ y(t_{n}) + h y'(t_n) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(t_n) + O(h^3)  \right]- \; \left[ y(t_{n}) + \frac{h}{2} \left( y'(t_{n}) + y'(t_{n})  + h y''(t_n) + O(h^2)\right) \right] = $

$\left[ y(t_{n}) + h y'(t_n) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(t_n) + O(h^3)  \right]- \; \left[ y(t_{n}) + h y'(t_n) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(t_n) + O(h^3)  \right] = O(h^3) $

Then, the implicit midpoint rule method is said to be of order $p = 2$.

Regards,

Comment: The step from the second to the third line is wrong without adding error terms. And also quite unnecessary, the comparison with $y(t_{n+\frac12})$ is more direct.

Answer (score 1):

First a correction: The implicit midpoint method proceeds by solving in each step the implicit equation
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h \cdot f \left(t_n + \frac{h}{2},\frac{y_n + y_{n+1}}{2} \right).
$$
One gets the local truncation error by replacing $y_k$ with $y(t_k)$ for an exact solution of $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ that is close to the numerical solution, for instance satisfies $y(t_n)=y_n$ or $y(t_{n+1})=y_{n+1}$, and then computing the defect in the above equation.

To keep the symmetry of the situation, insert an exact solution with $y(t_{n+\frac12})=y_{n+\frac12}$. Then with Taylor expansions
\begin{align}
y(t_{n+1})-y(t_n)&-h·f\left(t_n + \frac{h}{2},\frac{y(t_n) + y(t_{n+1})}{2} \right)
\\
&=y\left(t_{n+\frac12}+\frac{h}2\right)-y\left(t_{n+\frac12}-\frac{h}2\right)
\\&\qquad-h·f\left(t_{n+\frac12},y(t_{n+\frac12})+\frac{y(t_n) - 2y(t_{n+\frac12})+ y(t_{n+1})}{2} \right)
\\
&=h·y'(t_{n+\frac12})+\frac{h^3}{24}y'''(t_{n+\frac12})+O(h^5)
\\&\qquad-h·f\left(t_{n+\frac12},y(t_{n+\frac12})\right)-\frac{h^3}{8}·\partial_yf\left(t_{n+\frac12},y(t_{n+\frac12})\right)y''(t_{n+\frac12})+O(h^5)
\\
&=\frac{h^3}{24}\left(y'''(t_{n+\frac12})-3\partial_yf\left(t_{n+\frac12},y(t_{n+\frac12})\right)y''(t_{n+\frac12})\right)+O(h^5)
\end{align}
This confirms the local $O(h^3)$ truncation error.

---

For the test problem, just insert the function $f(t,y)=λy$ into the method step to get
$$
y_{n+1} = y_n + h \cdot λ \left(\frac{y_n + y_{n+1}}{2} \right),
\\~\\
\left(1-\frac{hλ}{2}\right)y_{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{hλ}{2}\right)y_n
\\~\\
y_{n+1} = \left(\frac{1+\frac{hλ}{2}}{1-\frac{hλ}{2}}\right)y_n
$$
and then check where $$\left|\frac{2+hλ}{2-hλ}\right|\le 1.$$