# Derive the implicit midpoint method using Taylor series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

So I gotta derive the Implicit Midpoint method using taylor series for an ODE $y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ and show that it is symmetric and A-stable.

So taylor series

$y(t)=y(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^3}{48}y'''(t_{n-1/2})+...$

and have to derive

$y_n=y_{n-1}+h_nf(t_{n-1/2},\frac{1}{2}(y_n+y_{n-1}))$

My attempt and where I'm stuck.

Note here we consider $t_{n-1/2}=t_n-\frac{1}{2}h_n$

So shuffling around...

$y(t)-y(t_{n-1/2})=\frac{h_n}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})+...$
$\implies y(t)-y(t_{n-1/2})=\frac{h_n}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})+...\implies \frac{y(t)-y(t_{n-1/2})}{h_n}=\frac{1}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})+...$

Also, $y(t_n)=y(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^3}{48}y'''(t_{n-1/2})+...$

and
$y(t_{n-1})=y(t_{n-1/2})-\frac{h_n}{2}y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{8}y''(t_{n-1/2})-\frac{h_n^3}{48}y'''(t_{n-1/2})+...$

Combining yields

$\frac{y(t_n)-y(t_{n-1})}{h_n}=y'(t_{n-1/2})+\frac{h_n^2}{24}y'''(t_{n-1/2})+O(h_n^4)$

Now, I'm having trouble putting this all together. Any pointers?

Here's link to derivation from wikipedia, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_method

Comment: Some more calculations on this topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270787/calculating-stability-and-order-of-implicit-midpoint-scheme. You should perhaps start from the midpoint quadrature scheme to find the general form of this, then use Taylor to confirm the order.

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful

Comment: Would you happen to know how to show if this numerical scheme is symmetric? the book says if $y_n=y_{n-1}+h_n\phi (y_{n-1},y_n,h)$ and $\phi(u,v,h)=\phi(v,u,-h)$

Comment: In general, how do you show a numerical method is symmetric? The stuff I found online don't seem to provide any clarification at all in how to determine this.

Comment: Just write down what $ϕ(u,v,h)$ is, the symmetry is quite easy to see.

Comment: Yes I see it now, the problem I was having was making the time variable $t_{n-1/2}$ negative and trying to work around that, but as you pointed out, it depends on h.